# Unable to translate bytes[92] at index 0 from specified code page to unicode?

Tags: c#, json, xaml, unicode, windows-8.1

This error occurs on the XAML of every page that takes data from the SampleData.json file. So this is any split pages or item detail pages.

This is the line on which the error occurs:

```
d:Source="{Binding Groups[1].Items, Source={d:DesignData Source=/SplitDataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:NewDataSource}}"/>
```

which is in the context of something like:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="itemsViewSource"
    Source="{Binding Items}"
    d:Source="{Binding Groups[1].Items, Source={d:DesignData Source=/SplitDataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:NewDataSource}}"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

The odd thing is, that all the content I'm looking for is displayed when the app is run. The errors I'm getting aren't causing the app to break or not work in anyway - except - that I can't see any of the content when looking at the designer. The pages are completely blank, bar what isn't dependant on the .json file.

I was getting the error originally described in this guide, so I followed the instructions, and now I'm getting the error in the title:

http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/09/winrt-argumentoutofrangeexception-no.html

I suspected it might be something to do with some punctuation I used in the .json file, so I removed any that wasn't essential, but no difference.

Thanks :) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your JSON file is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: Yep, it is. I tried with and without signature too, to see if it made a difference. It made no difference.

Comment: `translate bytes[92] at index 0`, means that -something- has loaded a chunk of data that originally was 92 bytes length. Have you checked **what** is it? Which file or other design-data that you use has is exactly **92** bytes long? Could you find it, hexdump it, and post it here? The error claims there's some encoding problem, so if you find&show us the hexdump of that data, then maybe someone will notice what's wrong with it. Also, your OS codepage will help, as it's the default encoding used when the readers cant understand the BOMs.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. How would I find out if a file is exactly 92 bytes long? That seems very small, and I don't have many that are small. I'm also looking at the hex for the SampleData.json file, and it seems to start with a ï»¿ although I'm fairly sure that wasn't there this morning.

Comment: I've literally gone through all 1734 files in the project, and I can't find one that's exactly 92 bytes long. I got close a few times, with 108 once, and some that are smaller than 92, but nothing on the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your json file new line type, if you are in windows, should be CRLF